# selectednodechanged event of treeview does not fire

Tags: asp.net, events, treeview

i have a project where i have a couple of pages. on my master page i have a treeview which is for navigation. the treeview is linked to a sitemap file.

the nodes are built like this:

--Node(invisible)
-----NavPoint1
-----NavPoint2
-----NavPoint3

so basically i have made the first node invisible so only its leaf nodes are visible. now i have different user roles: admin, user, guest, etc. for one of the menu items, the view will be different only when an admin accesses it. for that i wanted to implement a selectednodechanged event for the tree node. however it doesnt seem to be firing and i dont know what i did wrong.

here is my markup of the treenode which sites in a master page:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" NodeIndent="10" ImageSet="Simple"x OnSelectedNodeChanged="TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged">
                        <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="False" Font-Bold="true" />
                        <NodeStyle Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalPadding="0px" NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
                        <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
                        <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Bold="true" HorizontalPadding="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
                    </asp:TreeView>
```

here is my sitemap file:

```
<siteMapNode url="" title=""  description="">
        <siteMapNode url="Default.aspx" title="Home" description="" />
        <siteMapNode url="PersoenlicherKalender.aspx" title="Persönlicher Kalender" />
        <siteMapNode url="Gruppenkalender.aspx" title="Gruppenkalender"/>
        <siteMapNode url="DatenAendern.aspx" title="Daten ändern"/>
    </siteMapNode>
```

and this is my method for handling the event:

```
protected void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (TreeView1.SelectedNode == TreeView1.Nodes[3])
            {
                if (Session["Benutzerart"] == Enums.BenutzerTypen.Benutzer.Administrator.ToString())
                { lblUser.Text = "Erfolg!"; }
            }
        }
```

i would also be willing to use another control, it seems that this is a little harder than it should be...

Comment: Maybe you should have different site maps for different roles, and then bind sitemap depends on which role user is logged in. Not sure why you want to fire `SelectedNodeChanged` event.

Comment: Your event should fire on click. I see there is an `x` just before your `OnSelectedNodeChanged`. Verify if that is causing any trouble.

Comment: yes i have removed that, it was from a different event i tried. but it still doesnt work.

Comment: ok guys i have given up on this approach. i check for the user's role in the page_load event of the corresponding page now. then i just set controls to vivisble or hidden based on the user's rights.